# Keyword parsing in C/C++ extension for Python 3

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, visual-studio

I am currently trying to implement a Python module using C++. Official Python 3 docs provide an example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html#providing-finer-control-over-data-attributes), but to my surprise the code provided there throws errors in my Visual Studio 2017!

If you take a look at `Custom_init` function implementation, you will see a function call `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` that takes several arguments, including a keyword array `kwlist` declared 3 lines above (Example copy-pasted below):

```
static int
Custom_init(CustomObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    static char *kwlist[] = {"first", "last", "number", NULL};
    PyObject *first = NULL, *last = NULL, *tmp;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "|UUi", kwlist,
                                     &first, &last,
                                     &self->number))
        return -1;

    if (first) {
        tmp = self->first;
        Py_INCREF(first);
        self->first = first;
        Py_DECREF(tmp);
    }
    if (last) {
        tmp = self->last;
        Py_INCREF(last);
        self->last = last;
        Py_DECREF(tmp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However upon trying to declare a `kwlist` of my own like in example above, VS2017 throws the following error:

***a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"***

The simple thing would be to declare my own `kwlist` as `const`, but `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` expects `kwlist` as `char *`. (Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords))

Is there a way to deal with this without resorting to extremes like `const_cast`?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

One of the comments below suggested to simply copy from `const char*` to `char*` and I believe that will be the simplest approach to resolve this.

Comment: Yuck. I hate it when this happens. Python is new enough that this shouldn't happen.

Comment: You can always copy your `const char*[]` into a new local `char *[]` to pass to Python.  But it does seem odd that Python requires a non-const keyword list.

Comment: @0x5453 I cannot believe I've missed this! (D'oh!) Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of anything less horrible than

```
static char first[] = "first";
static char last[] = "last";
static char number[] = "number";
static char *kwlist[] = {first, last, number, NULL};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the strings as `std::string`s, and then use `std::string::data` to get your `char *`s

```
static int
Custom_init(CustomObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    static std::array<std::string, 4> keywords { "first", "last", "number", "" };
    std::array<char *, 4> kwlist;
    std::transform(keywords.begin(), keywords.end(), kwlist.begin(), [](auto & str){ return str.data(); });

    PyObject *first = nullptr;
    PyObject *last = nullptr;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "|UUi", kwlist.data(),
                                     &first, &last,
                                     &self->number))
        return -1;

    if (first) {
        auto tmp = self->first;
        Py_INCREF(first);
        self->first = first;
        Py_DECREF(tmp);
    }
    if (last) {
        auto tmp = self->last;
        Py_INCREF(last);
        self->last = last;
        Py_DECREF(tmp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use offsets into a single string literal

```
static char keywords[] = "first\0last\0number\0\0";
static char * kwlist = { keywords, keywords + 6, keywords + 11, keywords + 18  };
```